# How to plot errorbars in a grouped bar?

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, errorbar

I want to plot errorbar in my grouped bars. I wrote following code

```
x = categorical({'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'});
y = [6816,7215; 5824,6180; 4860,5200; 3860,4206; 2838,3185];
errlow = [238,337;270,355;303,297;291,340;259,382];
errhigh = [231,264;225,337;153,171;185,286;167,247];

b = bar(x,y);

hold on

xtips1 = b(1).XEndPoints;
ytips1 = b(1).YEndPoints;

er = errorbar(xtips1, ytips1, errlow(:,1), errhigh(:,1));    
er.Color = [0 0 0];                            
er.LineStyle = 'none';

hold on

xtips2 = b(2).XEndPoints;
ytips2 = b(2).YEndPoints;

er2 = errorbar(xtips2, ytips2, errlow(:,2), errhigh(:,2));    
er2.Color = [0 0 0];                            
er2.LineStyle = 'none';

hold off

ylim([2400 7600]);
```

Errorbars are displaying into the graph. Please have a look, they are straight over a, b, c, d and e but not on the bar as shown in the figure.

[image]

I want them on the associated bars ('GREEN' marked error should be on right bar whereas 'RED' marked error should be on left bar) as presented in the figure. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Answer here: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/438514-adding-error-bars-to-a-grouped-bar-plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the answer provided by the [MathWorks Support Team](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/profile/authors/4622813), as posted on [MATLAB Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102220#answer_111566) (with the exception of some minor modifications).

---

> *The ability to specify that the `errorbar` function should display the error bars inside the patches is not available in MATLAB.
> There are two work arounds for this limitation, usage of which depends on the release of MATLAB that you are using.*
>
> 1. *If you are using R2019a or earlier releases, find the center of each bar and pass this data into `errorbar` with the respective error values.*
> 2. *If you are using R2019b or later releases, retrieve the x coordinate of each bar using the `XEndPoints` property and [pass this data into `errorbar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.bar-properties.html#mw_3d0c5b61-b082-4c79-b9c6-a21152ae26ff).*
>
> *The following is an example of the above:*

```
% Example data
model_series = [10 40 50 60; 20 50 60 70; 30 60 80 90];
model_error = [1 4 8 6; 2 5 9 12; 3 6 10 13];
b = bar(model_series, 'grouped');
```

***For MATLAB R2019a or earlier releases:***

```matlab
hold on
% Find the number of groups and the number of bars in each group
ngroups = size(model_series, 1);
nbars = size(model_series, 2);
% Calculate the width for each bar group
groupwidth = min(0.8, nbars/(nbars + 1.5));
% Set the position of each error bar in the centre of the main bar
% Based on barweb.m by Bolu Ajiboye from MATLAB File Exchange
for i = 1:nbars
    % Calculate center of each bar
    x = (1:ngroups) - groupwidth/2 + (2*i-1) * groupwidth / (2*nbars);
    errorbar(x, model_series(:,i), model_error(:,i), 'k', 'linestyle', 'none');
end
hold off
```

***For MATLAB 2019b or later releases:***

```matlab
hold on
% Calculate the number of bars in each group
nbars = size(model_series, 2);
% Get the x coordinate of the bars
x = [];
for i = 1:nbars
    x = [x ; b(i).XEndPoints];
end
% Plot the errorbars
errorbar(x',model_series,model_error,'k','linestyle','none')'
hold off
```

[image]